# SOLVED? Parallelization of rsync (bash) through multiprocessing.Pool (Python) : The code works as intended but rsync throws strange errors

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, rsync, os.walk

[EDIT: I solved(?) the problem on my own and updated the question accordingly]

I have a Python script which performs daily backups of a large folder (with subfolders).
As the folder has become too large and the backup process takes too much time, being such process CPU-bound I needed to modify the script so to make use of the several CPU cores in the server.

NOTE: There probably are better modules and functions to be used in this use-case, but using `multiprocessing.Pool()` applied to a `subprocess.call` to `rsync` is a requirement from which I could not diverge.

1. I struggled for a couple of weeks on this because I always ended up having several duplicates in the destination folder (hence the original question); I now have found a clunky but working solution by splitting the file/folder paths and merging them again (using `os.path.join`): is there a better way to do this?
2. Although the script produces the exact backup of the original folder, I still get some suspicious rsync error messages during the execution and I'm worried that everything will crumble as soon as the wrong combination of processes gets executed: can anyone take a look at those and tell me if I need to worry?

Here is the (minimal working version of the) code I wrote, commented:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

#In this test /src/ and /dest/ are in the same folder of the script
source = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"src")
destination = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"dest")

def get_pathlist(folder):
    pathlist = []
    #No need for the FULL path of the dir/file
    #The source directory is in a global variable
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(folder):
        for f in files:
            #Extract the sub-folder (if any)
            path = root[len(folder):]
            #Extract the filename
            item = f
            #Store the RELATIVE path in a tuple
            pathlist.append((path,item))
        for d in dirs:
            #Extract the sub-folder (if any)
            path = root[len(folder):]
            #Extract the folder name
            item = d
            #Store the RELATIVE path in a tuple
            pathlist.append((path,item))
    #Return the list of tuples
    return pathlist

def backup(path):
    #Source = root, path[0] = sub-folder, path[1] = file/dir name
    #NB: We input the FULL path of the source file/folder
    src = os.path.join(source,path[0],path[1])
    #Destination = root, path[0] = sub-folder
    #NB: We input the destination folder only (no need for the file/folder name)
    dest = os.path.join(destination,path[0])
    subprocess.call(['rsync', '-azq', src, dest])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_pathlist = get_pathlist(source)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(len(src_pathlist),maxtasksperchild=1) as mpool:
        mpool.map(backup,src_pathlist)
```

As I mentioned the script produces the intended result but I get some strange errors from rsync.
The /src/ structure is as follows (for reference):

```
/src/
/1.txt
/Folder
/Folder/2.txt
/Folder/New_folder-A
/Folder/New_folder-B
/Folder/New_folder-C
/Folder/New_folder-A/3A.txt
/Folder/New_folder-B/3B.txt
```

The errors I get are:

```
rsync: change_dir "/Folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/Folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/Folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/Folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/Folder/New_folder-A" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir#3 "/Folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(720) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync: change_dir "/Folder/New_folder-B" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir#3 "/Folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(720) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Any improvement suggestions are VERY welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

src = os.path.expanduser("~/data/prod/")
dest = os.path.expanduser("~/data/prod_backup/")

def get_pathlist(folder):
    print(folder)
    pathlist = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        path = root[len(folder):]
        print(dirs)
        print(files)
        if dirs != []:
            for d in dirs:
                pathlist.append((path, d))
        for f in files:
            pathlist.append((path, f))

    return pathlist

def backup(path):
    source = os.path.join(src, path[0], path[1])
    destination = os.path.join(dest, path[0])
    subprocess.call(['rsync', '-arq', source, destination])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_pathlist = get_pathlist(src)

#    with Pool(len(src_pathlist), maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
    p = Pool(len(src_pathlist))
    p.map(backup, src_pathlist)
```

Comment: Explain your answer please

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

src = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/data/prod/")
dest = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/data/prod_backup/")

def get_pathlist(folder):
    pathlist = []
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        path = root[len(folder):]
        if dirs != []:
            for d in dirs:
                pathlist.append((path, d))
        for f in files:
            pathlist.append((path, f))

    return pathlist

def backup(path):
    source = os.path.join(src, path[0], path[1])
    destination = os.path.join(dest, path[0])
    subprocess.call(['rsync', '-arq', source, destination])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_pathlist = get_pathlist(src)

    with Pool(len(src_pathlist), maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
        pool.map(backup, src_pathlist)
```

I was able to get rid of some errors by traversing through directories first and then files. Also there are some changes in inner for loops for more efficiency. And thanks, your code helped me out as i was trying to do the same but making some small mistakes.